# Rearrange Dataframe with Datetime-Index to multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe with a Datetime-Index and just one column with a measured value at that time:

| Index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-01-01 05:00:00 | 2.8 |
| 2017-01-01 05:15:00 | 3.2 |

I have data for several years now, one value every 15 minutes. I want to reorganize the df to this (I'm preparing the data to train a Neural Network, each line will be one input):

| Index | 0 days 05:00:00 | 0 days 05:00:00 | ... | 1 days 04:45:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-01-01 | 2.8 | 3.2 | ... | 1.9 |
| 2017-01-02 | ... |  |  |  |

The fastest, most "python" way I could find, was this (with df being the original data, df_result the empty target df):

```
# prepare df
df_result = pd.DataFrame(index=days_array, columns=times_array)
# fill df
df_result = df_result.apply(order_data_by_days, df=df, log=log, axis=1)

def order_data_by_days(row, df):
    for col in row.index:
        row[col] = df.loc[row.name + col].values[0]
    return row
```

But this takes >20 seconds for 3.5 years of data! (~120k datapoints). Does anyone have any idea how I could do this a lot faster (I'm aiming at a couple of seconds).
If not, I would try to the the transformation with some other language before the import.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, if anyone else has this issue:

Step 1: create target `df_result` with index (dates, e.g. 2018-01-01, 2018-01-02, ...) as `datetime.date` and columns (times, e.g. 0 days 05:00:00, 0 days 05:15:00, ..., 1 days 04:45:00) as `timedelta`.

Step 2: use a for-loop to go through all times. Filter the original df each time using the `between_time-function`, write the filtered df into the target `df_result`:

```
        for j in range(0,len(times_array)):
            this_time = get_str_from_timedelta(times_array[j], log)
            df_this_time = df.between_time(this_time, this_time)
            if df_result.empty:
                df_result = pd.DataFrame(index=df_this_time.index.date, columns=times_array)
            df_this_time.index = df_this_time.index.date
            if times_array[j] >= timedelta(days=1):
                df_this_time.index = df_this_time.index - timedelta(days=1)
            df_result[times_array[j]] = df_this_time[pv]
```

Note that in my case I checked if the times are actually from next day (`timedelta(days=1)`), since my "day" starts at 05:00 a.m. and lasts until 04:45 a.m. the next day. To make sure they end up in the same row of `df_result` (even though, technically, the `date-index` is wrong here), I use the last `if`.